# How to generate a shapefile with UTM Grid precision level 100 m

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, utm, vector-grid

Does anybody know, if I can download from somewhere UTM Grid for zones 33 to 35 and U belt (for Poland) in shpfile or different format I can convert to shp. I need precision level 100 m. Is it possible to generate it in some GIS software?

Comment: This Grid must to have atribut (emblem 34 U FD 432879)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using [**Create Fishnet**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000) with cell heights and widths of 100.

The seconds step is to [**Define Projection**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000) on that feature class to tell it that the units are meters in the UTM zone of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS you can assign grids to a layout. Right click on the dataframe and select properties. There is a grids tab. This is good for labeling and print design. And PolyGeo's suggestion about creating a fishnet is great for creating an actual feature class of grid squares.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ESRI ArcGIS maps and data DVD, look there.  The setup is as follows:

http://www.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/esri_intl.htm

I think that the metadata will explain the sources used by ESRI.